# Javascript: call a function to return a value from within a function?

Tags: javascript, return

Bit complicated to phrase but I have one function that needs to call another one to get a value returned to use in the first function - an example:

The first function needs to get the variable gameTitle from the function getGameInfo()

```
function getGameInfo(){
     var gameTitle = "test game";

    if(gameTitle){
        return gameTitle;
    }else{
        return undefined;
    };

};

function getImages(){

    var gameTitle = getGameInfo();
     console.log(getGameInfo());

};
```

but for some reason this never works - it always returns "undefined" - I am extremely confused why this is happening

EDIT: 
I was given an answer in the comments by  Pointy -  this was not my whole code as this was an example but I was using  an asynchronous API and was trying to get the function to return a value from an callback hence the issue of undefined!!!

Comment: Your code does not return `undefined`.

Comment: [Works as is.](http://jsfiddle.net/dznsg9on/)

Comment: Here's a guess: this isn't really the code that's causing problems, and you didn't actually try this or you would have seen that it's not representative of the issue you're facing. Another guess: your real code involves an asynchronous API, and you're trying to return a value from a callback.

Comment: Actually that could be the issue with the asynchronous api ... thanks!!!

Comment: What returns `undefined`? `getGameInfo` or `getImages`?

Answer (score 3):

`getValue` returns correctly, so I assume your problem is that `testFunction` returns `undefined`. It is because you didn't specify it what to return, you only told it to print something on the console.
If you also want it to return something, add a return statement to it.

```
function testFunction(){

  var newValue = getValue();
  console.log(newValue);
  return newValue;
}
```

Comment: OK yes this is possibly what was intended by the question; however he did know to include a `return` statement in the "getValue" function.

Comment: Unlikely this is an issue, OP seems to understand concept of `return` statement. Wait a sec.. Anyway +1 for it :)